Installing --global windows-build-tools Errors

yarn global add windows-build-tools
npm install --global windows-build-tools
commands not working
I also downloaded Desktop Development with C++ with Visual Studio 2022. But it still doesn't work, I can't download it
I want to install windows-build-tools
